# Does bitcoind not support txindex=1 option in regtest mode?

Tags: bitcoind, regtest, bitcoin.conf

Is it possible to specify `txindex=1` option in bitcoin.conf or elsewhere?
It doesn't seem to work. Whenever I run `bitcoind -daemon`, it stops.

If I remove `txindex=1` from the conf file, it works.

I am using regtest mode.

Here is the conf file:

```
rpcuser=abc
rpcpassword=secret
regtest=1
rpcport=8332
txindex=1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If bitcoind stops, them you should have a look in your `debug.log` file.
Enabling `-txindex` with an already initialised blockchain (not your first regtest start) requires a reindex.

Either you start with `-reindex-chainstate` or you delete your `<bitcoin-data-dir>/regtest folder`